# Removing multiple kernel packages takes a really long time

Tags: grub2, kernel, dpkg

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 and I have a lot of old kernels that I want to remove.

[This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu) can help to find and remove them, but there is a problem:

> Each time `dpkg` removes a single kernel, it runs `/etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub` and `update-initramfs` over **all the kernels** currently remaining.

As a result, the uninstall takes forever!

I want to remove all the packages in one go, and then run `update-grub` once at the end.  How can I disable the unnecessary steps?

(I use `unattended-upgrades`.  Perhaps that's how I got into this situation.)

Comment: A closely related question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/681953/removing-older-kernels-takes-forever/728561#728561

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is what I did:

1. Edit the file `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig` (as root) and add the following line at the top: (*)

   ```
   exit 0
   ```
2. Then run `apt-get purge` or `dpkg -P` as suggested in the linked question, to remove the unwanted packages.  For example, I ran:

   ```
   sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg --list | grep -E 'linux-(image|signed-image|headers)' | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | grep -vF "$(uname -r | grep -o '[0-9.-]*' | sed 's/-$//')")
   ```

   *(Feeling nervous?  Put `echo` at the front to see what it will purge, before running it for real.)*
3. Then **don't forget** to edit `grub-mkconfig` again and remove the line:

   ```
   exit 0
   ```
4. Then finally run:

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

   to get your boot loader up-to-date.

This process recovered 11GB of space in under 30 minutes.

I also followed [this excellent suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/104370/133393) to prevent `unattended-upgrades` from building up my kernel packages again in the future.

> (*) I also considered disabling `/usr/sbin/dkms` and `/usr/sbin/extlinux-update` and `/usr/sbin/update-initramfs` using the `exit 0` trick, but these didn't save that much time, and they left files around in `/lib/modules/[kernel_version]/` and `/boot/initrd.img-[kernel_version]` so not really a good option.

Comment: +1 Nice. Don't forget to accept your answer by clicking the grey check mark next to it :)